# Out of memory in BlackBerry OS 5.0 SQLite 

Tags: sqlite, blackberry, java-me

I am not able insert data into my database sometimes. I am getting an `out of memory` exception even if the db file is empty.

The following is my code, please take a look at it. Thanks in advance for any suggestions.

```
public class ThreeptalkDAO {

private static ThreeptalkDAO service;
private static Database database;

public static ThreeptalkDAO getInstance() throws CustomException {
    if (service == null) {
        service = new ThreeptalkDAO();
        URI uri;
        try {
            uri = URI
                    .create("file:///SDCard/threeptalk/db/threeptalkdao.db");
            database = DatabaseFactory.openOrCreate(uri);
            // createMessagesTable();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("exp is:" + e.getMessage());
            Dialog.alert(e + e.getMessage());

            throw new CustomException(e.getMessage());

        } // here path is like
            // 'file:///SDCard/Databases/mytestApp/testdatabase.db'

    }
    return service;
}

public void createMessagesTable() throws CustomException {
    try {
        Statement statement = database
                .createStatement("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS messages(message_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,message,status,message_type_id,response,date_added,sender,office,sent_on,phoneno)");
        statement.prepare();
        statement.execute();
        statement.close();
    } catch (DatabaseException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        throw new CustomException(e.getMessage());
    }

}

public void insertMessages(Vector messages) throws CustomException {
    for (int i = 0; i < messages.size(); i++) {
        Messages m = (Messages) messages.elementAt(i);
        try {
            Statement statement = database
                    .createStatement("INSERT INTO messages (message_id,message,status,message_type_id, response,date_added,sender,office,sent_on,phoneno) VALUES ("
                            + m.getMessageID()
                            + ",'"
                            + m.getMessage()
                            + "','"
                            + "unread"
                            + "','"
                            + m.getMessageType()
                            + "','"
                            + "0"
                            + "','"
                            + m.getMdate()
                            + "','"
                            + m.getSender()
                            + "','"
                            + m.getOffice()
                            + "','"
                            + m.getSentOn()
                            + "','"
                            + WebserviceFactory.getInstance().getPhoneNo()
                            + "')");

            statement.prepare();
            statement.execute();
            statement.close();
        } catch (DatabaseException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            throw new CustomException(e.getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Where's the exception being thrown from? I don't think `outofmemory` means your database is full, it probably means your RAM is full on your BlackBerry.

Comment: How much free RAM and how much free disk space does your simulator claim to have?

Comment: ok. is it problem of simulator memory..i dnt know the memory of simulator . i am using jre 5.0 and 9550 simulator. but for the first also i am not able to create the table

Answer (score 3):

In BlackBerry OS 5.0, the available memory for Sqlite is quite limited - 512kb.  This means building lots of statements, or inserting large data, can easily consume all memory availble to Sqlite, even if the device reports large amounts of free memory.
It looks like you are constructing the insert statement string yourself, and doing it for each new row.  You would save yourself a lot of memory by using a prepared statement, and then binding the values into the statement.  This also has the advantage of avoiding sqlite injection issues, intentional or accidental.

Instead of directly entering the string values, create the statement outside of the loop, and then inside the loop reset and bind the same statement object:

```
Statement statement = database.createStatement(
    "INSERT INTO messages (message_id,message,status,message_type_id,"+
    "response,date_added,sender,office,sent_on,phoneno) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)");
statement.prepare();
for (int i = 0; i < messages.size(); i++) {
    Messages m = (Messages) messages.elementAt(i);    
    statement.reset();
    statement.bind(1, m.getMessageId());
    statement.bind(2, m.getMessage());
    // and so on, for all the arguments
    statement.execute();
}
```